# R grid() function on fixed aspect-ratio plot

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I've encountered a problem with R's grid() function on fixed aspect-ratio plots.

When plotting with a fixed aspect-ratio, R's default behavior seems to be to resize the plot *inside* the plot window, rather than resizing the plot window itself, as seen here:

[image]

Aside from the unsightly empty space on either side of the plot (this is minor, I can deal with it), this poses a problem when attempting to overlay a grid.  If I take the previous plot, and overlay a 10x10 grid using the grid() function, I get the following:

[image]

Note that the grid follows the entire plot window, not the fixed aspect-ratio plot.  This makes it very difficult (read: nearly impossible) to overlay a regular grid on a fixed aspect-ratio plot.  Does anyone know a good solution to this?

Edit:  If you want code to run (there's really not much information there), here you go:

```
x <- 1:1200
y <- rep(x,times=800)
dim(y) = c(1200,800)
png(file="EXAMPLE1.PNG",width=1000,height=500)
image(y, asp=1)
dev.off()
png(file="EXAMPLE2.PNG",width=1000,height=500)
image(y, asp=1)
grid(col="black",nx=10,ny=10)
dev.off()
```

Comment: can you add the code that you are using

Comment: I still don't understand your question. You seem to complain about the extra space but make no attempt to remove it with the arguments available in `image`. As for `grid`, that's just a quick way to add a grid to the *entire* plotting region. I would suggest using `abline` directly if you want to fine-tune your grid

Comment: Note that the image is 1200x800, which is /not/ a square.  Moreover, fine-tuning the size in par() is not practical when taking into account the need to change the margins to accommodate other features.

@rawr, I have no complaint about the extra space, it is trivial to size the window such that it is minimal (though still present).  It was intentionally exaggerated in the example to demonstrate the problem.

abline seems to work fine, though, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your x-axis is twice as long as the y-axis, so either use twice as many grid lines

```
png(file="EXAMPLE3.PNG",width=1000,height=500)
image(y, asp=1)
grid(20,10)
dev.off()
```

or use abline directly

```
png(file="EXAMPLE4.PNG",width=1000,height=500)
image(y, asp=1)
invisible(sapply(seq(-1,2,0.1),function(i){
      abline(v=i,h=i,col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",lwd = par("lwd"))
      }
      ))
dev.off()
```

Comment: The latter solution works well.  The former, unfortunately, is a PITA since the only size specification I can find includes the margins, which are not specified in units of pixels (while the PNG device specifies size in pixels).